# opening folder in web site structure in Windows

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to set up a hyperlink to open a Windows Explorer, so that it can display a folder on the web server that is within the web site.

So in IIS, we have `inetpub/MyWebSite/subFolder/Data/`

I would like to allow for a web page hyper link to open the folder `/Data`

I can set up a user account on the web server and only provide access to this folder. I can use ASP Membeship to restrict access here, and/or assign the `Network Service` acccount access.

I don't really care who can see this folder as anything that gets placed in here will only be temporary, and nothing is "Mission Critical" just a file that the web site will read and write to and then it gets deleted.

Any and all ideas and suggestions will be tested.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What type of files are these, plain text?

Comment: No actually, small databases.

Comment: So they really only to see the DB names in a list? If so, you can easily do this per my answer below. No need to grant access to the folder at all :)

Comment: Actually they need to have read/write and delete capabilities to the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a representation of the folder's contents (using a DirectoryReader and CSS) and display that. Don't actually try to display the physical folder.

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like FTP, and if it's on an intranet, why not create a share? much less work.

Comment: Well I have created a share, but part this server is a public facing web server and is not on the domain. Admin does not want to enable ftp and no domain credentials. So I am looking for alternatives.

Comment: you don't want FTP, but you do want user to have full control? what about enabling directory browsing for this directory?

Comment: I have done it, but for some reason, I am guessing since it is not on the domain, I am having issues accessing it. "Network path not found" The IP address is in the scope of our LAN though.